# VSCode Debugger pauses unexpectedly in node modules files

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

While running my nodejs server code through the VSCode Debugger it pauses weirdly in multiple node module library files. Then I just have to hit play button like a hundred times to finally run the whole code. This is so annoying. I have no idea how to fix it. I even tried skipping node module files and folder in launch.json file but it just doesn't seem to work. Below is my launch.json file.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible Node.js debug attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "skipFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/**/*.js",
                "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
              ]
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 5858
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I too had the issue. Just reinstall it will solve the issue.

Comment: I'm using a Mac. I did the same but no results. :( But Okay! I'll try again.

Comment: For program specify the file name explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

uncheck them and it will work smoothly

Comment: You're the best! Thank You So Much :)